# Ant in a Cuboid find shortest path: length, width and height of a cuboid are given. Output should display the shortest distance in floating point

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

An ant saw a box of sugar. It climbs to the top corner of the box to get inside. Unfortunately, the box has only few sugar cubes at the bottom corner opposite to the ant. Write a program to help the ant to find the shortest path to reach the sugar cubes.

Input and Ouptut Format:

Input consists of three integers corresponds to length, width and height of a cuboid. 
Output should display the shortest distance in floating point. Correct to two decimal places.

Sample Input and Output:

Enter the length 
5 
Enter the width 
6 
Enter the height 
7 
The Shortest distance is 14.81

The formula i used
minimum among (1) square root[(a+b)^2 + c^2] (2) square root[(b+c)^2 + a^2] (3) square root[(a+c)^2 + b^2]

The answer i am getting for same inputs is 13.42
Where am i going wrong?

```
    s1=x+y;
    s2=y+z;
    s3=x+z;
   s1sq=s1*s1;
   s2sq=s2*s2;
   s3sq=s3*s3;
   x2=pow(x,2.0);
   y2=pow(y,2.0);
   z2=pow(z,2.0);
   full1=s1sq+z2;
   full2=s2sq+x2;
   full3=s3sq+y2;
   sq1=sqrt(full1);
   sq2=sqrt(full2);
   sq3=sqrt(full3);
   min=sq1;
   if(sq1<sq2 && s1<sq3)
   min=sq1;
   if(sq2<sq3 && sq2<sq1)
   min=sq2;
   else min=sq3;
   Printf("%.2f",min);
   return 0;
```

Comment: And the OP should show some effort if they expect us to help.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: I have added the code i wrote

Comment: What type have you taken full1 to be > @user3352106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in the formulae. The way you're looking at it, you should write:

```
(a + sqrt(b^2 + c^2))
(b + sqrt(a^2 + c^2))
(c + sqrt(a^2 + b^2)).
```

And even then, you wouldn't get the shortest distance. To give an example,
suppose the cube is of 1x1x1 units with sides along the x, y and z axes. In order for the ant to get from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1), it can go from 
(0,0,0) -> (0,1,1) -> (1,1,1) 
or
(0,0,0) -> (0, 0.5, 0.5) -> (1,1,1)

The second path is the shorter one obviously.